# jQuery: why calling form validate method shows default error messages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have some form with custom validation:

```
customForm.validate({
  errorElement: 'p',
  errorClass: "error",
  rules: {
    phoneNumber: {required: true}
  },
  messages: {
    phoneNumber: "custom"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
  }
});
```

And when I call ('#customForm').validate(), it adds to page default error message.
[image]

How Can I remove this default message?

Comment: It seems to work as expected in this example - http://jsfiddle.net/aeho1v4q/ Can you add the relevant code so that the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Actually I'm calling validate() method from angularjs controller, I guess something wrong with it, because I can't reproduce it in simple way.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your validation message like this -

```
customForm.validate({
  errorElement: 'p',
  errorClass: "error",
  rules: {
    phoneNumber: {required: true}
  },
  messages: {
    phoneNumber: {required: "custom message here"}
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
  }
});
```